# R Shiny download xlsx after resolving a promise

Tags: r, shiny, future

Could you please give an insight of why my future-promised data table object causes a failure when trying to save it with `downloadHandler` and  `write.xlsx2`?

I have working everything else in such fashion:

```
## Server processing

shinyServer(
        function(input, output, session)
        {
                
        options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")
                
        library(DT)
        library(data.table)
        library(magrittr)
        library(ggplot2)
        library(highcharter)
        library(lubridate)
        library(future)
        library(promises)
        library(xlsx)
                
                
        dt_materials <- eventReactive(
        input$run_materials,
        {
                
                plan(multiprocess)
                
                ## reactive values
                
                dat_func <- function()
                {
                
                    ## Data processing
                        
                        
                    ## Return
                    
                    list(
                            output_tbl
                            , plo1
                            , paste0('Время обработки: ', round(Sys.time() - start_time), ' сек.')
                            , output_tbl_private
                            , dat_full
                    )
                }
                
                
                ## launch future
                
                future({
                        dat_func()
                })
                
        })


## Output

output$downloadDataMaterials <- 
                downloadHandler(
                        
                        filename = "tass_ru_materials.xlsx",
                        
                        content = function(file)
                                {
                                        dat_full <- dt_materials() %...>% `[[`(5)
                                        
                                        write.xlsx2(x = dat_full, file = file, sheetName = 'materials', row.names = FALSE)
                                }
                        
                        )
        
})
```

I get a server fault:

[image]

However, a simple example works fine when I change the content function:

```
content = function(file)
                                {
                                        dat_full <- data.table(x=1:10)
                                        
                                        write.xlsx2(x = dat_full, file = file, sheetName = 'materials', row.names = FALSE)
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this work using a blocking resolution, looks enough for now.

```
output$downloadDataMaterials <- 
                downloadHandler(
                        
                        filename = "tass_ru_materials.xlsx",
                        
                        content = function(file)
                                {
                                
                                        dat_full <- value(dt_materials())[[5]]

                                        write.xlsx2(x = dat_full, file = file, sheetName = 'materials', row.names = FALSE)
                                
                                }
                        
                        )
```